# redirecting a page not working

Tags: php

im trying to redirect the page but im getting an error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function redirect_to() in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\15_06_widget_corp-final\includes\session.php on line 11
```

session.php code

```
<?php
    session_start();

    function logged_in() {
        return isset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    }

    function confirm_logged_in() {
        if (!logged_in()) {
            redirect_to("login.php");
        }
    }
?
```

>
i tried changing to this

```
header('location: login.php');
```

but nothing is working

this is my redirect to function

```
function redirect_to( $location = NULL ) {
        if ($location != NULL) {
            header("Location: {$location}");
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where have you defined `redirect_to` ? Its not a PHP native function. `header()` should work provided there is no output being sent to browser before you call `header`. Not even a blank space

Comment: `redirect_to()` is not a native PHP function. You must define it somewhere and put the header line in that function.

Comment: What error did you get after you replaced it to `header('location: login.php)`?

Comment: The url in `header()` must be fully qualified. not relative.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ i just added the redirect function

Comment: drop the curly braces and use a full url.

Comment: im not having any error but the page is just not redirecting

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
redirect_to("login.php");
```

**With**

```
header('location : login.php');
```

Comment: Please note: `location` must be absolute path according to rfc2616.

Comment: im not having any error but the page is just not redirecting when i make these changes

Answer (score 0):

use `header` instead redirect_to with `exit;` just below it else sometime its giving error for headers.

```
header('location: login.php');
exit;
```

Comment: are you sure that its coming in the if condition?